# Collect all property names of filtered objects based on criteria

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, filter

I have an array as below

```
[
  {
    "id": 82,
    "name": "fromcreate_date",
    "displayName": "From Create Date",
    "uiControl": "DATERANGE",
  },
  {
    "id": 82,
    "name": "tocreate_date",
    "displayName": "To Create Date",
    "uiControl": "DATERANGE",
  },
  {
    "id": 83,
    "name": "p_is_ut",
    "displayName": "Is UT",
    "uiControl": "HIDDEN",
   }
]
```

I want to filter this array based on `uiControl === "DATERANGE"` and get only the **name property** of the filtered objects in an array as below.

```
outputArray = ["fromcreate_date", "tocreate_date"]
```

Comment: Try this: const result = this.data.filter(x => x.uiControl === 'DATERANGE').map(x => x.name);

Comment: Thx. That worked. I can accept your answer of u choose to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple one liner:

```
const outputArray = this.data.filter(x => x.uiControl === 'DATERANGE').map(x => x.name);
```